# Update Fragment after Broadcast Activity Close

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcast, geofence

My app utilises the GeoFence framework with events raised via broadcast receiver and a notification is displayed to prompt the user to "check in" if the DWELL event is fired.

Tapping this notification opens an activity to allow the user to provide more details regarding the "check in" and when submitted, the activity closes and returns back to the app home activity, which is a fragment host.

When returning back to the app home activity, the fragment which contains a history of "check ins" has not updated to show the new item added.

So, my question is, how do I update a fragment when an activity is closed that is raised by a broadcast receiver intent?

PS, I'm somewhat of a newbie when it comes to dev for Android so forgive me if I have misunderstood!

Comment: Read up on the Repository pattern, and using `ViewModel` and `LiveData`. You want to store your data in the repository and have your main activity's viewmodel observe that data. This would be the right way to do things, and it is a bit broad to put in a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. Before I read and confuse myself... data is currently stored in a small Firebase database. I'm presuming LiveData would support that?

Comment: Hey Richard, sorry for the absence - I have had other project work with a higher priority which resulted in me stepping back. I must correct myself, I'm actually using SQLite to store information, not Firebase

Comment: Right, SQLite out the box does not support live updates in the same way that Firebase does. You would incorporate the Room SDK in order to get that. So that definitely brings me back to the MVVM pattern I mentioned in my first comment (which is perfectly compatible with Room). I believe taking a bit of time to learn this way of working will more than pay for itself.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I will do some good ol' Googlin'!

Comment: Shaun, good luck, see if you can focus the question a bit more as you learn more around the MVVM pattern and the classes I mentioned. But I believe it is easy to understand - you will end up with 1 single repository for your data, a viewmodel for each screen that interacts between the screen and repository, and livedata fields that will refresh when your other activity comes back into view.